# C# String Formatting Dictionary Intellisense

Tags: c#, csv, intellisense, import-from-excel

I've been trying to bold and italicize a few strings in the following example but it's not working. Is it possible to edit the format of the string?

```
private TestQuickInfoSourceProvider m_provider;
    private ITextBuffer m_subjectBuffer;
    private Dictionary<string, string> m_dictionary;
    public TestQuickInfoSource(TestQuickInfoSourceProvider provider, ITextBuffer subjectBuffer)
    {
        m_provider = provider;
        m_subjectBuffer = subjectBuffer;

        //Methods and their description, good for unique keywords AKA QuickInfo words
        m_dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        m_dictionary.Add("adapt", "<b> Process given file </b>\n"
```

**This is the output** 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/smDUF.png

What is the proper way to format the string?

Edit///

Found an easier way to do it with a large amount of data through CSV.

Comment: How are you writing the output and to where?  Please provide the rest of your code.

Comment: @STLDeveloper This is clearly a Visual Studio extension And this seems like some kind of intellisense popup..

Comment: Hi @STLDeveloper I apologise, yes it is an intellisense popup where hovering above a certain string/text will give us a popup to tell us something. I need to bold the heading of said process to allow my team to have an easier time understanding certain strings.

Comment: @user3185569 yes, it is. I would want to see the output bolded instead of the bold tags <b></b> which is clearly wrong in the attached output. Is there anyway to work around it? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential part of your code (which isn't included in your post) is the implementation of the **AugmentQuickInfoSession** method. I am assuming you are currently simply returning the string values from your `m_dictionary` there.

Getting formatting results in QuickInfo requires a bit more work. Let's take a look at the definition of [AugmentQuickInfoSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.iquickinfosource.augmentquickinfosession.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
void AugmentQuickInfoSession(IQuickInfoSession existingQuickInfoSession, IList<object> quickInfoContent, out ITrackin)
```

The `quickInfoContent` is a list of *object*. If you return a `String`, it'll not be formatted. However, if you return a `TextBlock` object, you can include formatted text.

Example code:

```
var textBlock = new TextBlock { TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap };

var boldRun = new Run("This is a bit of bold text.");
boldRun.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
textBlock.Inlines.Add(boldRun);

var normalRun = new Run("This is not very bold.);
textBlock.Inlines.Add(normalRun );

...

quickInfoContent.Add(textBlock);
```

Comment: Hi! @paul-jan Thanks for helping me out, I did some research and I came across the function fontStyle. I was wondering if it was possible to format a particular string for it to have different colors?

Such as 

m_dictionary.Add("continue", "will stop the execution of current loop & continue with next \n" +
                          "Syntax: #continue\n "
                          );

One example being the "continue" be blue and the rest of the string be of another color? I'm trying to get the quickinfo/mouse hover information to easier on the eyes.

Comment: If the approach with the multiple Runs in a TextBlock works out, then all you need to do is put "continue" in a Run of it's own and set the run.ForeGround to Brush.Navy (or whatever color you desire).